Change of Integral measure Involving a Supremum and Minimization with a Function on a Standard Probability Space
Let $(X,\mathcal B, \mu)$ be a Standard Probability space and $0<\beta<1$. Let $A\in \mathcal B$ such that $0<\mu(A)<\infty$. Let $\varphi:A\to \mathbb R$ be a map. Define $\omega:=\sup\left\{t>0: \mu(\{x\in A: \varphi(x)\ge t\})\ge \beta\right\}.$ Now I want to show that $$\int_0^1 \mu(\{x\in A: \varphi(x)\ge s \omega\})ds=\frac{1}{\omega} \int_A \min\{\varphi(x),\omega\}d\mu(x).$$ I know that we can use Radon-Nikodym theorem to change the measure on integral, but here I am unable to solve this. Please help me to solve this. Thank you for your valuable time and efforts.

$$
    \begin{align*}
      \int_0^1 \mu\{x \in A: \varphi(x) \ge s \omega\}ds &= \int_0^1 \int_A 1\{\varphi(x) \ge s \omega\}d\mu(x)ds\\
      &= \int_A \int_0^1 1\{\varphi(x) \ge s \omega\}dsd\mu(x)\\
      &= \int_A \int_0^1 1\left\{s \le \dfrac{\varphi(x)}{\omega}\right\}dsd\mu(x)
    \end{align*}
$$
here, we can swap the integral is due to Fubini and the fact that $0 < \mu(A) < \infty$. For the inner integral, notice that, for a fixed $x \in A$, we have
$$
     \int_0^1 1\left\{s \le \dfrac{\varphi(x)}{\omega}\right\}ds = \begin{cases} \int_0^1 ds = 1 = \dfrac{\omega}{\omega}, \text{ if } \varphi(x) > \omega\\
\int_0^{\varphi(x)/\omega} ds = \dfrac{\varphi(x)}{\omega}, \text{ if } \varphi(x) \le \omega \end{cases} = \dfrac{1}{\omega}\min\{\varphi(x), \omega\}
$$
Therefore,
$$
    \int_A \int_0^1 1\left\{s \le \dfrac{\varphi(x)}{\omega}\right\}ds d\mu(x) = \dfrac{1}{\omega} \int_A \min\{\varphi(x), \omega\}d\mu(x)
$$
